# Why the sourceViewController property in UIStoryboardSegue is an "id"

Tags: ios, objective-c, uikit, storyboard, uistoryboardsegue

In the `UIStoryboardSegue` class, the property `sourceViewController` is obviously a `UIViewController`. Why did Apple mark this property as an `id`?

```
@property(nonatomic, readonly) id sourceViewController;
@property(nonatomic, readonly) id destinationViewController;
```

Wouldn't it be easier to use or understand using `UIViewController *`, like

```
@property(nonatomic, readonly) UIViewController *sourceViewController;
@property(nonatomic, readonly) UIViewController *destinationViewController;
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason Apple uses ids here and in many other places is to allow flexibility and prevent obsolescence.

Despite the name of the property, `destinationViewController` may not always return a `UIViewController` object. Or more specifically, Apple didn't want to refactor these methods if a year down the line they have some new, special view controller that does not inherit from `UIViewController`. So, using ids prevents obsolescence.

Also note that you may not always want to cast the returned object to a `UIViewController.` For example, if your view controller is embedded inside a `UINavigationController` that will be returned by the destinationViewController. Although `UINavigationController` is a child of `UIViewController`, in most cases you don't want to cast it as such because you typically want to grab its view controller from within the `viewControllers` property, like this:

```
// unwrap the controller if it's embedded in the nav controller.
UIViewController *controller;
if ([segue.destinationViewController isKindOfClass:[UINavigationController class]]) 
{
    UINavigationController *navController = 
           (UINavigationController *)segue.destinationViewController;

    controller = [navController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0];

 } else {

    controller = segue.destinationViewController;
}
```

So, this design allows flexibility for the developer.

Comment: Since UINavigationController is a UIViewController subclass, why do id instead of UIViewController?

Comment: Ack. You are right. Completely forgot this was part of the same hierarchy. I think what Apple are trying to indicate is that while it may be true at present, it won't necessarily always be true that the returned object is in the `UIViewController` hierarchy. Today in iOS all view controllers are in the same hierarchy. Tomorrow? Who knows.

Comment: Yeah, very possibly. Interesting perspective.